# indexing a subset of elements from a 4D array in R

Tags: r, regression

i am new to using R . i am using the [cglasso](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cglasso/cglasso.pdf) package in R for one of my projects. The [coef.glasso](https://rdrr.io/cran/cglasso/man/coef.cglasso.html) function returns a 4D array of dimension 13470 * 5 * 10 * 10 (for my dataset) . this 4D array contains 2D coefficients matrices of dimension 13470 * 5 corresponding to a grid of 10 * 10 hyperparameters. i want to iterate over the grid of 10 * 10 hyperparameters and extract the 13470 * 5 2D coefficient matrix corresponding to each of them . **In one line** my question is How do i extract 2D matrices of dimension 13470 * 5 from a 4D matrix of dimension 13470 * 5 * 10 *10 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we have the following array (substitute your actual dimensions):

```r
d <- 5:2
arr <- array(seq_len(prod(d)), dim = d)
```

We can split the array into a list of slices in the 1st and 2nd dimension.

```r
list <- split(arr, slice.index(arr, seq_along(d)[-c(1:2)]))
```

Then, we can re-set the dimensions and we'll have 2D matrices of the 1st and 2nd dimension in a list.

```r
list <- lapply(list, function(x) {
  dim(x) <- d[1:2]
  x
})
```